# realizar consulta con ajax y mostrar en input text

Tags: ajax

Deseo obtener un valor de una tabla a través de una consulta. El resultado lo obtengo pero en un `DIV`, lo deseo en una caja de texto.
Index.php

```
<html>

<head>
 <title>Ejemplo sencillo de AJAX</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
function enviar(){
  //var n =  document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var datos={
                "nombre": $("#nombre").val(),
              }

$.ajax({
type:'post',
url: 'prueba_consulta.php',
data: datos,
//data: {nombre:n},
success: function(d){
  $("#respa").html(d);
}

});
return false;
}
</script>


<?php
include 'prueba_consulta.php';
?>

<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" size="30" name="" id="nombre">
  <input type="button" name="" value="enviar" onclick="enviar()">
  <div id="respa"></div><!-- Aca si sale el valor-->
  </form>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo($row['nombre_site']);?>"><!-- Aca NO sale el valor-->
</body>
 </html>




Prueba_consulta.php

<?php
//************ conexion a BD ***************
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("mantenimiento",$con);


 $filtro=$_POST["nombre"];
 $rs= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registro_energia_temp WHERE nombre_site like '%$filtro%' order by id_energia desc ;"); 

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

$nombre_site= $row['nombre_site'];
echo $nombre_site; //este valor se completa en el DIV y deseo mostrarlo en la caje de texto
?>
```

De antemano muchas gracias. Exitos!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar el valor en un input debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<input type="text" id="idinput">

$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: 'prueba_consulta.php',
    data: datos,
    //data: {nombre:n},
    success: function(d){
      $("#idinput").val(d);
    }
});
```

Simplemente es asignarle un `id` a tu `input`, capturarlo y con `.val()` darle su valor !

Comment: ya habia realizado dicho cambio: <form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" size="30" name="" id="nombre">
  <input type="button" name="" value="enviar" onclick="enviar()">
  <input type="text" id="respa">
</form>

luego puse este valor: <div id="respa"><input type="text" value="<?php 
  echo $nombre_site;?>"></div>
Pero nada. Gracias por su apoyo

Comment: y te funcionó ?

Comment: La verdad no funciono. Como dije al inicio cundo el resultado se da en un div, si sale pero cuando lo quiero llevar el resultado a un input text, no sale.

Gracias

Comment: Muéstrame el pedazo de código que tienes en el success del $.ajax

Comment: <script>
function enviar(){
  //var n =  document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var datos={
                "nombre": $("#nombre").val(),
              }

$.ajax({
type:'post',
url: 'prueba_consulta.php',
data: datos,
//data: {nombre:n},
success: function(d){
  $("#respa").html(d);
}

});
return false;
}
</script>

Muchas gracias

Comment: En la respuesta te estoy mostrando que para asignar un valor a input debes usar .val() y no .html() por lo cual debes crear otro id para tu input que sea diferente al de div y hacer lo que te mostré en la respuesta